# How to make background color show?

Tags: html, css

I have a login modal and I want there to be a blue background. I do not understand what is wrong with my CSS.

I want the div for my content to  be 200px height and 300px wide. I thought giving it a specific height and width would fix the issue but it has not.

I expect my content to have a white background in a 200px by 300px white box,but the white bakcgound will not show.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding img {
  width: 55%;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#login-content {
  border: 10 px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px background-color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
  <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
        <div id="login-modal">
          <div id="login-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder="username">
              <input type="password" placeholder="password">
              <button>Log In</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div>
        <h1>Guys</h1>
        <h2>dhkjsdhkjh duhfsduhfdiu fudshfisduhus usihfksdjfhsdiuh ushfkjdshfidsu kjhfudihf dihakdhf djkhksdj idhjdsshf siudhk shadjkhfisdu fskjahfdudd jkshfiusdh feuidhdhsui dsduhskdj.</h2>
        <button>Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Ladies</h1>
        <h2>Resolve is an easy and fun way to make quick cash while you help guys turn into men you would date! Give them honest feedback that would help them improve. Receive five dollars for every review! </h2>
        <button id="login">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="appad">
        <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In addition to the answers, you should learn about linters. You have a missing end tag for a div. You also have missing `;` for your CSS. They are a good tool to have around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your CSS.

1. It's `#login-content` and not `.login-content`. Since it's an id.
2. You're missing a semi-colon after `width`.

```css
#login-content {
    border: 10 px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Working snippet with the changes:

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

html, body{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:100%;
}

body{
 min-height:100%;
 min-width:100%;
 background: url("images/newnewgirls.jpg");
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 position:relative;
 
}
.container{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.container2{
 width:80%;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
}

header{
 padding:1em;
 margin:0;
}
header #branding{
 float:left;
}

header #branding img{
 width:55%;
}


header nav{
 float:right;
 margin-top:0.5em;
}

header nav li{
 display:inline;
 padding:1em;
}

header nav li a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

#login-modal{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align:center;
}

#login-content{
 border: 10 px solid black;
 height:300px;
 width:500px;
 background-color:white;
 text-align:center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password]{
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
 <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <div  id="branding">
    <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
    <div id="login-modal">
     <div id="login-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <form>
       <input type="text" placeholder="username">
       <input type="password" placeholder="password">
       <button>Log In</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div class="container2">
   <div>
    <h1>Guys</h1>
    <h2>dhkjsdhkjh duhfsduhfdiu fudshfisduhus usihfksdjfhsdiuh ushfkjdshfidsu kjhfudihf dihakdhf djkhksdj idhjdsshf siudhk shadjkhfisdu fskjahfdudd  jkshfiusdh feuidhdhsui dsduhskdj.</h2>
    <button>Get Started</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Ladies</h1>
    <h2>Resolve is an easy and fun way to make quick cash while you help guys turn into men you would date! Give them honest feedback that would help them improve. Receive five dollars for every review!  </h2>
    <button id="login">Get Started</button>
   </div>
   <div class="appad">
    <h2>App Coming Soon!</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element has the ID `login-content`, not a class. Change `.login-content` to `#login-content` on your CSS.